# How to cancel a CSS style set by 'hover child' selector on event?

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu

I am making a CSS based menu, with submenu items that pop up when the root element is hovered. the problem I have is that I want the CSS menu to close when I click an item in the list, but at that point I am still technically hovering over the top element, so I figured I had to use javascript to hide the menu. But when I set the display property, I set it forever and it overrides the hover selector of the parent node. And so the submenu doesn't show up anymore.
This must be pretty common, but I can't find any answers...

Any help much appreciated!

html:

```
<ul class="level1">
    <li>one
        <ul class="level2">
            <li id="test">two</li>
            <li>three</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
.level1 li:hover > ul {
    display: inline;
}

.level2 {
    display: none;
}
```

js:

```
document
  .getElementById('test')
  .addEventListener('click',function () {
     this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
     // After this the menu doesn't open anymore
     // because the style is overriden
});
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv9yU/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv9yU/14/).

```
<ul class="level1">
    <li class="hoverMe">one
        <ul class="level2">
            <li id="test">two</li>
            <li>three</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
.hoverMe:hover > ul {
    display: inline;
}
```

```
var test = document.getElementById('test');
test.onclick =  function () {
    this.parentNode.parentNode.className = "";
};

var level1 = document.getElementsByClassName('level1')[0];
level1.getElementsByTagName("li")[0].onmouseover =  function () {
    if (this.className != "hoverMe") {
        this.className = "hoverMe";
    }
};
```